# Php excel import is not working on new server

Tags: php, excel

I am using php excel reader to read excel file but while importing
the file on new server it is showing this page is not working.I have also given the  0777 permission to my folder but then also it is not importing
the excel file data.But on my old server this code is working fine.Please find the below code and let me know is there any code mistake or server setting is required to read phpexcel file.

```
<?php
      $file_path = 'clientupload/'.$upload_data["file_name"];

                    // ----------------------------------------------------
                    $this->load->library('PHPExcel');
                      //Here i used microsoft excel 2007
                    $objReader= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

                      //Set to read only
                    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

                      //Load excel file
                    $objexcel=$objReader->load($file_path); // error in this line
                     //  echo "hello";die;
                    $objWorksheet = $objexcel->getActiveSheet(0);

                    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();


?>
```

It is showing below error:
**This page isn’t working
216:xx:xx is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**

Comment: if this code work on the other server obviously problem with server configuration

Comment: yes but if it is related to server configuration,then any one please suggest what kind of setting is need for that.

Comment: enable php errors to see error details